# Historical reason to define a matrix vector product the way it is

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, math-history, transformation

What is the reason why we defined a `matrix vector product` (a transformation) this way:

> $$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\  a_3 & a_4  \\  \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} b_1\\  b_2\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1\cdot b_1 + a_2\cdot b_2 \\  a_3\cdot b_1 + a_4\cdot b_2\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

I know that when we want to represent a transformation, we care about the values that we're gonna multiply the vector's pieces, but why we use like a **linear combination** mechanism to multiply the vector's pieces?

I know that this may be a good reason:

- We can create new vectors with more or less dimensions than the original vector, just by having one, two, or more lines in the matrix (os less lines).

PS: I can't just say that this is derived from the `matrix matrix product`, because this type of product is derived from the `matrix vector product` definition, so any 'proof' or reason that uses `matrix matrix` product definition will be circular.

Comment: Its a convenient shorthand.

Comment: This is very difficult to parse.

Comment: [Relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/motivation-behind-definition-of-matrix-multiplication/24469#24469) (I think--I'm having a hard time understanding the question).

Answer (score 1):

In spite of your PS, I believe that `matrix matrix` product is the reason, since every $n\times m$ matrix $A$  can be seen as linear transformation $\mathcal{A}: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$. If you choose basis $\{e_1, \;... \;,e_n \}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and basis $\{f_1, \;... \;,f_n \}$ for $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $A$, $A_{ij} = a_{ij}$, gives you information about $\mathcal{A}$-images of $f_j$-s: 
$$\mathcal{A}f_j = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ij}e_i\text{.}$$

If you have two such linear transformations $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ (with corresponding matrices $B$ and $C$) for which composition $\mathcal{B}\circ \mathcal{C}$ can be computed, the `matrix matrix` product of $B$ and $C$ gives you matrix $BC$, which corresponds to linear transformation $\mathcal{B}\circ \mathcal{C}$.

I agree that the last fact is not intuitive and my personal opinion is before the `matrix matrix` product was defined, they had asked themselves

`Which matrix corresponds to composition of two linear transformations?`

Let be  $\mathcal{C}:X\to Y$ and $\mathcal{B}:Y\to Z$. Choosing basis for $X$ ($e_i$,), $Y$ ($f_i$,) and $Z$ ($g_i$,), it can be directly computed that $i$-th
component of $(\mathcal{B}\circ \mathcal{C})e_j$ equals to
$$\sum_k b_{ik}c_{kj}$$
so the `matrix matrix` product should be defined as it is nowadays.