General formula multiplying square matrices of a specific kind.
I was wondering if there is a general formula to know the result immediately of these kind of multiplications:
$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.
So, I want to be able to know what the product of 2 square matrices will look like when the colums are the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n$ being 3 in the example above.
Edit: this post was kind of a brainfart, since I know what permutation matrices are. For some reason I couldn't find the general formula for multiplying them. This question is deemed not useful since this question was answered before. (See comments). However, I do want to thank the people that have answered.

u can consider the multiplication of matrix as linear combination of row or column vectors.

What do you mean? @syqwq

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/matrix-multiplication-interpreting-and-understanding-the-process

These are permutation matrices.  Do you know how to multiply permutations?  Better yet, they are orthogonal, so $P^T=P^{-1}$

These are permutation matrices.
Here is how to quickly assemble the product matrix $P_{\alpha\times \gamma}$ of two permutation matrices $H_{\alpha\times \beta}$ and $V_{\beta\times \gamma}$:
$p_{rc} = \begin{cases}
1  & \quad\text{if }h_{rx}=1\text{ and }v_{xc}=1;\\
0 & \quad\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$
Each row and each column in $P$ will have exactly one entry with 1, because the product of permutation matrices is a permutation matrix too.

These are permutation matrices. Consider the first matrix, $P_{1}$. In its
first row, the 1 is in the 3rd column, which we can write $1\rightarrow 3$;
in the second row the 1 is in the first column, $2\rightarrow 1$; in the
third row the 1 is in the 2nd column, $3\rightarrow 2$. We can write down
these results as the permutation $[3,1,2]$. When $P_{1}$ premultiplies a
matrrix $M$, it permutes the rows of $M$, so the rows of $P_{1}M$ are the
rows of $M$ in the order $[3,1,2]\,$. In this case that leads to the
identity matrix. But since here $M=P_{2}$ is also a permutation matrix for
permutation $[2,3,1],$ the result will be the permutation matrix for the
product of the permutations $[3,1,2].[2,3,1]$ where the permutation on the
left is done first. This product is $[1,2,3]$.
We can work this out directly. Start with row 1 of $P_{1}\,$, which says
that $1\rightarrow 3$ \ Then we look at row 3 of $P_{2}$ to find $
3\rightarrow 1,$ so overall $1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 1$ or $1\rightarrow 1$
, so the first row in the product matrix has the 1 in column 1. Then we
start with the second row of $P_{1}$ and find $2\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2$
so the second row in the product has the 1 in column 2. For the third row, $
3\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 3$, so the third row has the 1 in column 3. We
find again that the product is the identity matrix.
